# Display the unmatched record from top table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table 1

| Col1 | Col2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 02/25/2020 |
| A | B | 02/25/2020 |
| A | B | 03/20/2020 |
| A | C | 02/21/2020 |

```
select * 
from Table1 
where Date between 2020-02-20 and 2020-02-27
```

Table 2

| Col1 | Col2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 03/20/2020 |
| D | E | 03/20/2020 |

Need to compare the Table 1 to Table 2 and if col1 and col 2 values are same that records should not display from the Table 1

So the output shpuld be from Table1

| Col1 | Col2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 03/20/2020 |

Comment: use `NOT EXISTS`. Please refer to documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15   By the way, you need to use single quote around those date in your query

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the rows from Table1 which does not exist in Table2 based on Col1 and Col2.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 
   WHERE T1.col1 = T2.col1
     AND T1.col2 = T2.col2
)
AND T1.Date between '2020-02-20' and '2020-02-27'
```

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller I thought the code is self explanatory, but I just added the comments what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Use an outer join:

```
select a.* 
from Table1 a
left join Table2 b on a.col1 = b.col1
  and a.col2 = b.col2
where Date between '2020-02-20' and '2020-02-27'
and b.col1 is null
```

whose `where` clause filters for rows that do *not* have a join.